# UI gameover score

Tags: unity, c#, scene2d

I have gameover canvas and i like in gameover canvas to show finaly distance i make with PlayerPrefs but doesnt work because is on same scene what can i do for this problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Distance = 0.0f;
    private int difficultyLevel = 1;
    private int maxDifficultyLevel = 20;
    private int scoreToNextLevel = 20;
    public Text distanceText;
    public carSpawner spawn;
    public carController car;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Distance >= scoreToNextLevel)
            LevelUp();

        Distance += Time.deltaTime * difficultyLevel;
    }

    void LevelUp()
    {
        if (difficultyLevel == maxDifficultyLevel)
            return;

        scoreToNextLevel *= 2;
        difficultyLevel++;


        spawn.delayTimer -= 0.1f;
        car.carSpeed += 1;
        Debug.Log(difficultyLevel);
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class iuManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioManager au;
    public Score score;
    public Button[] buttons;
    public carController car;
    public bool gameOver;
    public Canvas GameoverCanvas;
    public GameObject resumee;
    public GameObject res;
    public GameObject l;
    public GameObject easy;
    public GameObject medium;
    public GameObject hard;
    public GameObject back;
    public GameObject backk;
    public GameObject Shop;


    // Return the app's public key.
    public string AndroidPublicKey
    {
        // In a real app, return public key instead of null.
        get { return null; }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        gameOver = false;
        GameoverCanvas.enabled = false;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if (gameOver == false)
        {
            score.distanceText.text = string.Format("Distance : {0}Km", (int)score.Distance);
        }
    }


    public void gameOverActivated(){
        gameOver = true;
        GameoverCanvas.enabled = true;
    }



    public void play (){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level1");

    }

    public void Pause (){
        if (Time.timeScale == 1) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            foreach (Button button in buttons) {
                button.gameObject.SetActive (true);
                res.SetActive (false);
                resumee.SetActive (true);
                Shop.SetActive(true);
                back.SetActive (false);
            }
            au.carSound1.Pause();
            au.carSound2.Pause ();
        }
    }

    public void UnPause(){
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            foreach (Button button in buttons) {
                button.gameObject.SetActive (false);
                res.SetActive (true);
                resumee.SetActive (false);
                Shop.SetActive(false);
                back.SetActive (false);
            }
            au.carSound1.UnPause();
            au.carSound2.UnPause ();
        }
    }


    public void Replay(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }


    public void Menu(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menuScene");
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }


    public void Exit(){
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void Levels(){

        foreach (Button button in buttons) {
            button.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            resumee.SetActive (false);
            res.SetActive (false);
        }

        easy.SetActive (true);
        medium.SetActive (true);
        hard.SetActive (true);
        back.SetActive (true);
    }

    public void LevelsMenu(){

        foreach (Button button in buttons) {
            button.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

        easy.SetActive (true);
        medium.SetActive (true);
        hard.SetActive (true);
        backk.SetActive (true);
    }



    public void Back(){
        foreach (Button button in buttons) {
            button.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            resumee.SetActive (true);
            res.SetActive (false);
        }

        easy.SetActive (false);
        medium.SetActive (false);
        hard.SetActive (false);
        back.SetActive (false);
    }

    public void BackMenu(){

        foreach (Button button in buttons) {
            button.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }

        easy.SetActive (false);
        medium.SetActive (false);
        hard.SetActive (false);
        backk.SetActive (false);
    }

    public void LevelEasy(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level1");
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void LevelMedium(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level2");
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void LevelHard(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level3");
        if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

[image: In Game]

[image: GameOver]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I add the code.

Comment: You already have a _Distance_ text on the overlay canvas. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: i like to add finaly distance from game to game over canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce these fields:

```
public Score _score;
public Text _gameOverCanvasDistanceText;
```

Then edit your `gameOverActivated` method like this:

```
public void gameOverActivated()
{
    gameOver = true;
    _gameOverCanvasDistanceText.text = _score.Distance.ToString();
    GameoverCanvas.enabled = true;
}
```

You also need to assign these newly introduced fields in the inspector.

---

**Offtopic:** I suggest you take a look at [.Net naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).